# How do I create a reusable mailto link in ModX?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I want to create a link to an email address like `<a href="mailto:somebody@provider.com">somebody</a>`.

I tried to use a weblink resource (which gets an id of 20) with mailto:person1@provider.nl as link value and render this in my content with the tag [[~20?~]]. (and different variations of it)

But ModX renders it as `<a href="index.php?id=20">somebody</a>` This is not what I want.

So how do I do this properly, so that I can reuse this resource in several places in the website?

This link needs to be editable for a 'Content editor' with reduced rights, so I don't think a chunk is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because to do this you need to create [weblink](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/weblink):

[image]

[image]

and this is works as expected in Wayfinder/PdoMenu:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
`[[~20]]` - will output `alias` field. You need to output `content` field. To do this use `pdoField` snippet (part of pdoTools):

```
[[pdoField?&id=`20`&field=`content`]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but I'm not using WayFinder nor PdoMenu to pull in the resource.
I have another Page resource that should be able to use the Weblink resource like this: TinyMce has a link button which shows a dialog to form the link. In the search field under the General tab you can enter the name of the Weblink resource. If found it puts [[~20]] in the Link URL field.
In the actual webpage this renders as index.php?id=20 in the href attribute of my link.
I would have expected the 'mailto:somebody@provider.nl' though.